# C++ Template function with dynamic variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

im looking for a -std=gnu++17 (or 20 if already available) solution to work with objects and malloc. there i want to have a template function to alloc memory with malloc and construct the object. the object itself can be anything, so it might need 10 arguments in the constructor or none. how can i template function support this? the idea should be similar to printfs variable argument list, but here, its not arguments to print but variables, to call the constructor.

there is a lot ongoing with the new c++ standarts but its also pretty confusing if you are not used to it. is someone really up to date with those c++ features and can help out?

**THIS DISCUSSION SHOULD NOT INCLUDE "HOW TO ALLOCATE MEMORY AND CONSTRUCT OBJECTS". TEMPLATE CODING IS OF INTERESST**

```
template<typename T, typename... args>
T * malloc_and_construct()
{
    T* pobj = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
    if(pobj) new (pobj) T(args...);
    return pobj;
}
template<typename T>
void destruct_and_free(T* pobj)
{
    if(pobj) {
        pobj->~T();
        free(pobj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using `new` and `delete`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ya im aware of that. unfortunatelly i cannot use new and delete, only exception is new placement to construct. only interessted in the template function. look at the malloc function only as a demo code. this discusstion should not be about how to allocate memory in c++.

Comment: You are looking for [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: @BlueTune yes i saw this, but i dont understand it. do you have a simple example for me to study?

Comment: Check out the implementation of `std::make_unique` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), you probably want something similar.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok. thanks. i look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```cpp
template<typename TClass, typename ... TArgs>
TClass* malloc_and_construct(TArgs&& ... args)
{
    auto* ptr = malloc(sizeof(TClass));
    if (ptr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    return new (ptr) TClass { std::forward<TArgs>(args)... };
}
```

Comment: I'd use `(...)` instead of `{...}` here, to be consistent with the similar standard functions, and to avoid unexpected behavior with e.g. standard containers.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T * malloc_and_construct(Args &&... args)
{
    T* pobj = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
    if(pobj) new (pobj) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return pobj;
}
template<typename T>
void destruct_and_free(T* pobj)
{
    if(pobj) {
        pobj->~T();
        free(pobj);
    }
}

struct A
{
    A(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) { printf("A %d %d\n", a,b); }
    ~A() { printf("~A\n");  }
    private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B
{
    B() { printf("B\n"); }
    ~B() { printf("~B\n"); }
};


int main()
{
    A * a = malloc_and_construct<A>(2, 3);
    B * b = malloc_and_construct<B>();

    destruct_and_free(a);
    destruct_and_free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

result:

A 2 3
B
~A
~B